# Python static variables implemented in a decorator don't reset

Tags: python, python-decorators, static-variables

I have the code here that implements a decorator for static variables.  However, I find that if I run this function multiple times, the static variables are not re-initialized each time I call the function.

```
def static_vars(**kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        for k in kwargs:
            setattr(func, k, kwargs[k])
        return func
    return decorate


@static_vars(count=0)
def rolling_serial(val):
    '''
    For a vector V = [v_1, ..., V_N] returns a serial
    index.

    so for V = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
    a resulting vector will be generated
    V_hat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    '''
    temp = rolling_serial.count
    rolling_serial.count += 1

    return temp

# invoke it like this
from useful import (rolling_serial)

df = <...some dataframe with a column called ts>

self.df['ts_index'] = self.df.ts.apply(rolling_serial)
# Example output a new column, sa: [1, 2, 3, ..., N]

# My issue arises if I run it again
df = <...some dataframe with a column called ts>
self.df['ts_index'] = self.df.ts.apply(rolling_serial)
# output: [N+1, N+2, ...] instead of restarting at 0
```

If I restart the jupyter kernel, the static variable clears out.  But I would prefer to not have to restart the kernel.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think what you see is exactly what one would expect. The decorator is not executed each time you call rolling_serial, but only once at startup. Since there is only one function `rolling_serial`, there is also just a single variable `count`. Perhaps if you describe what you are _trying_ to achieve, we can suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: Static variables aren't *supposed* to reset each time you call a function. If you want them to reset every time, that's what ordinary local variables are for. Why are you using this decorator at all?

Comment: It looks like you may be missing the fact that `apply` calls your function repeatedly, and you're relying on `count` *not* resetting between those calls. A global function with a function attribute doesn't seem like the tool for the job; a closure factory could be appropriate, but creating this new column with something other than `apply` is probably the best way to go.

Comment: I am looking for a self-contained solution for the static variable behavior (functions keeping state) because they are hard to discover, and not a very typical pattern that is used in my organization.  Trying to make them "just work".  Thanks for the recommendation on closure factory, I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator is called only once, not with each call to your function. Exactly, it's called at the definition time:

```
def static_vars(**kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        for k in kwargs:
            print(kwargs)
            setattr(func, k, kwargs[k])
        return func
    return decorate


@static_vars(count=0)
def rolling_serial(val):
    '''
    For a vector V = [v_1, ..., V_N] returns a serial
    index.

    so for V = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
    a resulting vector will be generated
    V_hat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    '''
    temp = rolling_serial.count
    rolling_serial.count += 1
    return temp

print('---- BEGIN ----')
print(rolling_serial(10))
print(rolling_serial(20))
print(rolling_serial(30))
```

Prints:

```
{'count': 0}
---- BEGIN ----
0
1
2
```

The `kwargs` you have as parameter in `static_vars()` will become closure and will be incremented with each call to `rolling_serial()`.

One solution is to transfer the variables through globals():

```
# This function creates decorator:
def static_vars(**global_kwargs):
    # This is decorator:
    def decorate(func):
        # This function is called every time:
        def _f(*args, **kwargs):
            for k in global_kwargs:
                globals()[func.__name__+'_'+k] = global_kwargs[k]
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return _f
    return decorate

@static_vars(count=0, temp=40)
def rolling_serial():
    global rolling_serial_count, rolling_serial_temp

    temp1, temp2 = rolling_serial_count, rolling_serial_temp
    rolling_serial_count += 1
    rolling_serial_temp += 1
    return temp1, temp2

print(rolling_serial()) # prints (0, 40)
print(rolling_serial()) # prints (0, 40)
print(rolling_serial()) # prints (0, 40)
```

Comment: What do you suggest if I want to re-initialize the static variables every time I want to generate a new sequence?

Comment: @AaronSoellinger I updated my answer, using globals() to set variable each time a decorated function is called.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` decorator is what's getting in the way, since it is intended to decorate once, at function definition time.

So, trim that out and simplify it to `setattr` keyword args on passed-in function.  This is what you'd have to do manually, minus the `@` syntax shorthand.

```
def static_vars(func, **kwargs):
    for k in kwargs:
        setattr(func, k, kwargs[k])
    return func


def rolling_serial(val):
    temp = rolling_serial.count
    rolling_serial.count += 1
    return temp    

static_vars(rolling_serial, count=0)
print (rolling_serial(3))
print (rolling_serial(3))

#reset it
static_vars(rolling_serial, count=0)
print (rolling_serial(3))
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
```

Also, FWIW, you don't use `val` and dataframe is not germane, it would have been better to just post some expected results of `rolling_serial` on its own.